# What are the available options to filter contents in typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, json, typeahead.js

i have a suggestion input field to search on my own JSON to give suggestions on available train stations in UK. I've managed to get that done via following code.

```
$.getScript('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.bundle.min.js', function() {
    // script is now loaded and executed.
    var stations = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: function(datum) {

            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.simplename);
        },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        sorter: function(a, b) {

            if (a.name < b.name) {
                return -1;
            } else if (a.name > b.name) {
                return 1;
            } else return 0;
        },
        prefetch: {
            url: 'Rails_Feed.json',
            cache: false,
            transform: function(data) {
                return $.map(stations.sorter(data.stations), function(station) {
                    //debugger;
                    //console.log(station.id);
                    if (station.name == 'United Kingdom') {
                        return {
                            id: station.id,
                            name: station.localizedNames[0].extendedValue,
                            country: station.name,
                            dest: station.tags.rails['stationCode'],
                            simplename: station.localizedNames[0].value,
                        };
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    });

    // Instantiate the Typeahead UI
    $('#origin-rlp').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    }, {
        limit: 10,
        name: 'originName',
        display: 'name',
        value: 'name',
        source: stations,
        templates: {
            empty: [
                '<div class="empty-message">',
                'no suggessions',
                '</div>'
            ].join('\n'),
            suggestion: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                return '<div class="address"><span class="icon icon-train"></span>&nbsp;' + data.name + '</div>';
            }
        }
    }).on('typeahead:selected', function(obj, datum) {
        //console.log(datum);
        var DestData = new Array();
        DestData = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(datum));
        $('#origin-dest').val(DestData["dest"]);
    });
});
```

I've several questions of this as i recently learned and used typeahead.js.

1. i have filter results from country in my transform function.is this
   the correct way to do?.cant't i pass that as a condition in
   datumTokenizer function.
2. is there a way to limit/filter suggestions as the character user
   type should be in the beginning of the word or is there any function
   to sort it to get exact match to top(example:when user types "lo"
   it should show all items that start from 'lo' and after them shows
   other suggestions. Like 'Loch Awe, Dalmally, UK' should come before 'Kyle of Lochalsh, Kyle, UK') ?

a sample JSON object is as follows in case u need it

```
{
      "name": "United Kingdom",
      "localizedNames": [
        {
          "value": "London",
          "extendedValue": "London,UK"
        }
      ],
      "tags": {
        "rails": {
          "stationCode": "GBLO"
        }
      },
}
```